# g++ enables wrong flags at -Os

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

at the moment I am doing some experiments with the GNU C++-Compiler and the -Os optimization option for minimal code size. I checked the enabled compiler flags at -Os with the following command:

```
g++ -c -Q -Os --help=optimizers | grep "enabled"
```

I got this list of enabled options:

```
-faggressive-loop-optimizations [enabled]
-falign-functions               [enabled]
-falign-jumps                   [enabled]
-falign-labels                  [enabled]
-falign-loops                   [enabled]
-fasynchronous-unwind-tables    [enabled]
                 ...
```

This seems a bit strange, because I also looked up, which flags should be enabled at -Os, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and under the -Os section it is written that all the `falign-` options should be disabled for code minimization.

**Q:** So is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here ? Cause after reading what the `falign-` flags do I really think they should be disabled in -Os !

My gcc-version is 4.9.2 and I am working on Arch-Linux.

Already thanks for helping :)

Comment: I can reproduce with the same compiler, and also with the older 4.4.7, except `falign-loops` is missing there.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43861

Comment: Ahh thanks, so this seems to be a known bug. I will try the patch from bugzilla or disable the options explicitely.

Comment: Good find Hans. I was going to suggest Trezz file a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: So is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here ? Cause after reading what the falign- flags do I really think they should be disabled in -Os

I think Hans did a good job of finding part of the problem. Its definitely a documentation bug. But no one from GCC commented on why `-Os` enabled them, so you might not have all of the information.

Older ARM devices were very intolerant of unaligned accesses. Older arm devices included ARMv4 and I think ARMv5. If you performed an unaligned access, you would get a `SIGBUS` (been there, done that, got the tee shirt).

Modern ARM devices fix up unaligned accesses like x86 processors do, so you no longer get a `SIGBUS`. Instead, you just take the performance penalty.

You should try to specify an architecture in case those options are an artifact from older ARM device support. For example, `-march=armv7`. If you find it on ARMv6 and ARMv7, then that could still be a bug. It depends if the GCC team decided the tradeoff was sufficient for ARM (code size vs performance penalty).